# React JS Fluent ui onRenderTitle

Tags: reactjs, fluentui-react

Hello I am new to reactcand have to use fluent ui

I am trying to chnage a custom optionlabel with

**onRenderTitle={(options) => `${options.name} (${options.roll_number})`}**

Mycode:

```
<Dropdown
  placeholder={"Select your School"}
  onChange={(event, val) => {
  if (val === null) {
  setSelectedSchool("")
  } else {                                                                       
  setSelectedSchool(val.key);
  }
   }}

  value={selectedcounty}

   options={getschool.filter(x => x.county === selectedcounty).map((school, key) => (
   {
     key: school.name, text: school.name
   }
    ))}
       onRenderTitle={(options) => `${options.name} (${options.roll_number})`}
/>
```

Im getting
[image]

The result that I want:
[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`onRenderTitle` is a function which returns `Element` not `String`. Type of **options** is `IDropdownOption[]`

```
<Dropdown
  ...
  onRenderTitle={options => <span>{options[0].key} ({options[0].text})</span>}
/>
```

[Codepen example.](https://codepen.io/savkelita/pen/qBrGEBz)